# ive been working on this mini project in tkinter

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

> I've been doing this project using Tkinter and I've made an if statement that says if the answer that the user put is cs print out a label says correct else print wrong and I've tested it but it keeps saying its the wrong answer when I type 'cs'

```
import Tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("800x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Quiz App', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
label1.pack()


def playbuttonclicked():
    label1.destroy()
    playbtn.destroy()
    quitbtn.destroy()
    label2 = tk.Label(window, text='What is the short form of computer science', font=("Arial Bold", 10)).pack()
    txtbox = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
    txtbox.place(x=250, y=400)
    useranswer = txtbox.get()

    def chkanswer():
        if useranswer == 'cs':
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text='Correct').pack()
        else:
            lbl = tk.Label(window, text='Wroooong').pack()
    submitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', command=chkanswer).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)



playbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Play', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=playbuttonclicked)
playbtn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)


def quitbuttonclicked():
    window.destroy()


quitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Quit', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=quitbuttonclicked)
quitbtn.place(x=530, y=570)

window.mainloop()
```

so can you help me, please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You read what is in the Entry (textbox) directly after you have created it. It doesn't wait until you enter a text.

Also, you create the Entry inside the `playbuttonclicked()` function and the reference `txtbox` will not be available after the function has ended.

In my example I create the Entry in global namespace and the `playbuttonclicked()` function only places it on the window.

When the user clicks on the `Submit` button, the `chkanswer()` function will get the string from the Entry and then compare it to the correct answer.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("800x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Quiz App', font=("Arial Bold", 25))
label1.pack()

txtbox = tk.Entry(window, width=50) # Create Entry in global namespace

def chkanswer():
    useranswer = txtbox.get()       # Get contents from Entry
    if useranswer == 'cs':
        lbl = tk.Label(window, text='Correct').pack()
    else:
        lbl = tk.Label(window, text='Wroooong').pack()

def playbuttonclicked():
    label1.destroy()
    playbtn.destroy()
    quitbtn.destroy()
    label2 = tk.Label(window, text='What is the short form of computer science', font=("Arial Bold", 10)).pack()
    txtbox.place(x=250, y=400) 
    useranswer = txtbox.get()
    submitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', command=chkanswer).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

playbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Play', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=playbuttonclicked)
playbtn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

def quitbuttonclicked():
    window.destroy()

quitbtn = tk.Button(window, text='Quit', font=("Arial Bold", 10), command=quitbuttonclicked)
quitbtn.place(x=530, y=570)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: if your answer is the only one that's available until 5 am if its the only one ill do it btw thx for answer